# Internationalization(i18n) in Javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I have used internationalization(i18n) in the past in order to make a web-page bilingual. I am wondering whether internationalization(i18n) is present in every JS library or only in few libraries like knockout or node.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of frameworks out there doing i18n for specific frameworks.

I would highly recommend reading my article at medium: https://medium.com/@jamuhl/i18n-frameworks-the-unfair-showdown-8d436cd6f470

My personal point here is to bet on a major framework which runs on every js environment, so you learn it once and use that everywhere. In case of i18next this means support for: http://i18next.com/docs/ecosystem/#frameworks